# Find objects having a specific value in a specific property in Autocad drawing

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I have objects in Autocad drawing with property named `Base`. I am trying to find all objects in that drawing with `Base` property has a specific string value such as "`Pipe`".

I can iterate objects in the drawing and get all object ids. Then I get all properties of object with that Id and check if property named `Base = "Pipe"`.

Iteration performance is not good enough. Is there any way to directly get object ids that has property named `Base = "Pipe"`?

Here is how I iterate through all objects:

```
    List<ObjectId> ObjectIds = new List<ObjectId>();

    foreach (Document Document in Documents)
    {
        Database Database = Document.Database;

        using (Transaction Transaction = Database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            for (long i = Database.BlockTableId.Handle.Value; i < Database.Handseed.Value; i++)
            {
                ObjectId Id;

                if (Database.TryGetObjectId(new Handle(i), out Id))
                {
                        ObjectIds.Add(Id);
                }
            }

            Transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

And here is how I get all properties of the objects in my `ObjectIds` collection.

```
public static DataLinksManager DataLinks
{
    get
    {
        if (null == _DataLinks)
        {
            StringCollection Coll = Autodesk.ProcessPower.DataLinks.DataLinksManager.GetLinkManagerNames();

            if (Coll.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Coll[0] != string.Empty)
                {
                    _DataLinks = Autodesk.ProcessPower.DataLinks.DataLinksManager.GetManager(Coll[0]);
                }
            }
        }

        return _DataLinks;
    }
}

private static DataLinksManager _DataLinks;

foreach(var Id in ObjectIds)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Properties = DataLinks.GetAllProperties(Id, true);
    // I check existence of my property and if so its value.
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you currently have.

Comment: are you trying to find all block references with 'Base' attribute value equal to 'Pipe'?

Comment: Yes @vinayan that is what I'm trying to do in an acceptable performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone needs, here is the code that is solution to my problem. The trick is the `Iterate` method. This is based on [this article](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-through-an-entire-database.html) by Philippe Leefsma. What I add to this method is a list of `ObjectClass` properties of found `ObjectId` instances. My sample dawing has around 8500 `ObjectIds`. However what I'm interested in is objects with base classes `acppasset` and `acppdynamicasset` and count of such objects is 90.

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using AcadApp = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application;

public static void GetObjects()
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, ObjectId>> ObjectIds = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ObjectId>>();

    List<string> Filter = new List<string>() { "acppasset", "acppdynamicasset" };

    foreach (Document Document in this.Documents)
    {
        ObjectIdCollection Ids = this.Iterate(Document, Filter);
        if (null != Ids) foreach (var Id in Ids.OfType<ObjectId>()) ObjectIds.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, ObjectId>(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Document.Name), Id));
    }

    this.Results = new Dictionary<string, List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>();

    foreach (var Id in ObjectIds)
    {
        try
        {
            var Properties = this.GetObject(Id.Value);
            if (null == Properties) continue;

            var Base = Properties.Where(x => x.Key == "Base").FirstOrDefault();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Base.Value)) continue;

            if (!this.Results.ContainsKey(Base.Value)) this.Results.Add(Base.Value, new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>());

            this.Results[Base.Value].Add(Properties);
        }   catch { }
    }
}

 public ObservableCollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }

 public ObjectIdCollection Iterate(Document Document, List<string> Filter = null)
        {
            ads_name Instance = new ads_name();
            Database Database = Document.Database;

            ObjectIdCollection ValidIds = new ObjectIdCollection();

            // Get the last handle in the Database
            Handle Handseed = Database.Handseed;

            // Copy the handseed total into an efficient raw datatype
            long HandseedTotal = Handseed.Value;

            for (long i = 1; i < HandseedTotal; ++i)
            {
                string Handle = Convert.ToString(i, 16);

                int Result = acdbHandEnt(Handle, ref Instance);
                if (Result != 5100) continue; // RTNORM

                ObjectId Id = new ObjectId(Instance.a);

                if (!Id.IsValid) continue;

                try
                {
                    if (null != Filter)
                    {
                        if (!Filter.Contains(Id.ObjectClass.Name.ToLower())) continue;
                    }

                    using (DBObject DBObject = Id.Open(OpenMode.ForRead, false))
                    {
                        ValidIds.Add(Id);
                        DBObject.Dispose();
                    }
                }   catch { }
            }

            return ValidIds;
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetObject(ObjectId Id)
    {
        if (Command.DataLinks != null) try { return Command.DataLinks.GetAllProperties(Id, true); } catch { return null; }
        return null;
    }

public static DataLinksManager DataLinks
{
    get
    {
        if (null == _DataLinks)
        {
            StringCollection Coll = Autodesk.ProcessPower.DataLinks.DataLinksManager.GetLinkManagerNames();

            if (Coll.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Coll[0] != string.Empty)
                {
                    _DataLinks = Autodesk.ProcessPower.DataLinks.DataLinksManager.GetManager(Coll[0]);
                }
            }
        }

            return _DataLinks;
        }
    }

private static DataLinksManager _DataLinks;

public Dictionary<string, List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>> Results { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The slow performance here is because it attempts to read all the objects and check if it contains any attribute. As far as I know, the attributes exist only for block references(inserts). So if [selection filters](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/index.html?url=files/GUID-125398A5-184C-4114-9212-A2FF28FC1F1D.htm,topicNumber=d30e726632) are used, we could get direct access to only those records based on the filter criteria.

I found a pretty easy example [here](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/block-reference-selection-using-selection-filter.html) using selection filter that selects all blocks with a particular name.

Copying a part of that code for reference. This selects only the block references. You can iterate from here.

```
TypedValue[] filterlist = new TypedValue[1];
filterlist[0] = new TypedValue(0, "INSERT");
SelectionFilter filter =  new SelectionFilter(filterlist);

PromptSelectionResult selRes =  ed.SelectAll(filter);

if (selRes.Value.Count != 0)
{
    SelectionSet set = selRes.Value;

    foreach (ObjectId id in set.GetObjectIds())
    {
        BlockReference oEnt = (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite);
        //do something with oEnt..;
    }

}
```

If you can [add complexities to your filter](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/index.html?url=files/GUID-125398A5-184C-4114-9212-A2FF28FC1F1D.htm,topicNumber=d30e726632), you will need to iterate only a very small set.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @vinayan. Using a selection filter works if I select objects. In my case I should not select any object, just loop through the drawing database.

Comment: @Demir - nice that you worked out yourself! slightly modified so as to avoid user interaction :)